# PowerShell, SVN and asterisks

Tags: powershell, svn

I'm trying to add a property on a file, basically setting `svn:needs-lock` to `*`. However it appears PowerShell, or SVN, is misinterpreting the asterisk, especially when there's other files in the working copy (in my case, they're unversioned files).

Basically, all of the following variations give me the error: `svn: E155010: The node: 'R:\SVN\repo\web\root\x' was not found.`, where `x` is an unversioned file in the working copy (and for the benefit of doubt web.config *is* versioned).

```
svn propset svn:needs-lock * web.config
svn propset svn:needs-lock '*' web.config
svn propset svn:needs-lock "*" web.config
svn propset svn:needs-lock `* web.config
svn propset svn:needs-lock "`*" web.config
svn propset svn:needs-lock `"*`" web.config
```

So I've tried quoting the asterisk, escaping the asterisk (PowerShell uses the backtick as the escape char) and escaping the quotes (in case they were being interpreted by PowerShell and not being passed to SVN).

Now I know the actual value of `svn:needs-lock` doesn't matter, so I'm using something else instead, but in the spirit of inquiry, curious minds want to know.

Comment: Powershell interprets * as a character, it's the command that changes it to a wildcard. So looking into svn for something like a -LiteralPath switch would be the way to go.

For example New-Item considers it a char, but New-ItemProperty considers it a wildcard.

Comment: What behaviour do you get when trying it in a bog standard `cmd` console?

Comment: @arco444 - for it to work in cmd, it needs to be (after some trial and error): `svn propset svn:needs-lock '*' file.name`

Comment: @arco444 - Sorry I tell a lie (lack of error does not mean it's worked as expected). According to `svn propget` I've got a value of `'*'` instead of `*`.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that if you get it working in `cmd` you might be able to use the same command as part of an `Invoke-Expression` command, or maybe even try that anyway, but otherwise you've already covered all the options I could think of.

Comment: All Subversion does is check whether the  `svn:needs-lock` is on the file or not. It doesn't care about the value of the `svn:needs-lock` property itself. Setting the value of `svn:needs-lock` to  `*` is merely tradition. If `*` is giving you trouble, just use another value.

Comment: @David - I know that: see my last paragraph :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap arguments in the array:

```powershell
& 'svn.exe' @('propset', 'svn:needs-lock', '*', 'web.config')
```